# Remove grub from blank hdd

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, uninstall, format

I was getting rid of linux on a spare hdd i have laying around and i asked a friend to remove it and he messed up and formatted the entirething without getting rid of grub. The drive isnt showing up on any systems and i cant boot to it without crashing my new rig. Please help.

Comment: Is there a reason that wiping the drive with DBAN wouldn't work?

Comment: You can do this with any of several tools. DBAN is probably over kill, you can use scrub or dd. I doubt grub is the cause of your problems, you can format and manage partitions on a hard drive with gparted with grub installed.